# Proving that the limit of a given test function is a valid delta function

Tags: limits, vector-spaces, distribution-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am a physics student trying to gain a better mathematical understanding of the theory of distributions and namely the definition of the Dirac-Delta function. I understand that the defining properly of a delta function is the following integral property (integrated over the real line).

$\int f(x)δ(x-a) = f(a)$

I also understand that there are multiple delta "functions" that are the limit of so called test functions that satisfy the above integral property. My question is, for a given choice of a delta function (i.e. for a given limit of a test function), eg. $δ(x) = \lim_{a\to 0} \frac 1{|a|\sqrt{pi})} e^{-(\frac xa)^2} $ , how would you prove that this choice satisfies the above integral property and thus can be considered a valid delta function?

Thank you

Comment: Deltas are not the limits of test functions. In the theory of distributions there is no such thing as integrating against a delta. The Dirac delta is defined as the distribution (i.e. a linear functional, an object that maps functions to real numbers) that maps a test function to its value at $a$ $$\delta_a(\phi) = \phi(a)$$ In order to prove a sequence of functions approaches a delta, one must prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\:f_n(x)\phi(x) = \phi(a)$$ for any arbitrary test function $\phi$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ah, I see. For the integral requirement you have stated, what is the meaning behind the subscript n on the function f? I'm not sure I understand the "sequences of functions" concept.

Comment: Something like $$f_n(x) = \frac{n}{1+n^2x^2}$$ $$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{ndx}{1+n^2x^2}\phi(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{1+t^2}\phi\left(\frac{t}{n}\right) = \pi \phi(0)$$ which means $f_n \to \pi \delta_0$ in the sense of distributions.